# WF4 rehosted - get selected activities in a flowchart

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I select a few activities in a flowchart and trying to delete them. In the ModelChanged event of the current ModelService, i am trying to get which items were selected :

```
 var selections = Designer.Context.Items.GetValue<Selection>().SelectedObjects;
```

I would expect a list containing my selections, but instead i get back the flowchart which contains those items. I can't figure out how to reach those specific activities.

I saw an answer to a similar question  :

```
            NativeActivity activity = wd.Context.Items.GetValue<Selection>().
  PrimarySelection.GetCurrentValue() as NativeActivity;
```

but this give me the same result, meaning the flowchart containing the activities which are to be deleted.

Is there any way to get over the flowchart and retrieve those items?

Comment: What do you really want to do? The problem is at which point are you trying to access `Selection` object.

Comment: @Jota I am trying to delete some activities from my flowchart. I catch all of this in the ModelChange event where i have to do some work to bring back the connections via the ModelItem as you told me on my last issue. All goes fine when i delete the items one by one. That way, only one FlowStep in the Flowchart Nodes will have the Next property set to null. I will try to give an example: i want to delete the first 3 activities from the flowchart. But at the first hit in ModelChange, i will have the first one removed, and the others 2 present but i think in an inconsistent state.

Comment: @Jota Every time hitting the ModelChange i want to set the Next property of my ModelItems to a next valid activity. At this moment i am setting the FlowChart StartNode to point to the next one but in fact, this will be deleted when i will hit the ModelChange next time. And i get an exception after the job is done, but not while the job is done. So basically if i delete the first 3 items, i want to StartNode of the Flowchart ModelItem to point the the fourth one.